# how character pointer could be used to point a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, typecast-operator

First of all I am beginner in C++. I was trying to learn about type casting in C++ with strings and character pointer. Is it possible to point a string with a character pointer?

```
int main() {
    string data="LetsTry";
    cout<<(&data)<<"\n";
    cout<<data<<"\n"<<"size "<<sizeof(data)<<"\n";
    //char *ptr = static_cast<char*>(data);
    //char *ptr=(char*)data;
    char *ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data);
    cout<<(ptr)<<"\n";
    cout<<*ptr;
}
```

The above code yields outcome as below:

```
0x7ffea4a06150
LetsTry
size 32
`a���
`
```

I understand as ptr should output the address 0x7ffea4a06150

Comment: You can use [`std::string::c_str`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) that *"Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current value of the string object."*

Answer (score 1):

Historically, in C language strings were just a memory areas filled with characters. Consequently, when a string was passed to a function, it was passed as a pointer to its very first character, of type `char *`, for mutable strings, or `char const *`, if the function had no intent to modify string's contents. Such strings were delimited with a zero-character (`(char)0` a.k.a. `'\0'`) at the end, so for a string of length 3 you had to allocate at least four bytes of memory (three characters of the string itself plus the zero terminator); and if you only had a pointer to a string's start, to know the size of the string you'd have to iterate it to find how far is the zero-char (the standard function `strlen` did it). Some standard functions accepted en extra parameter for a string size if you knew it in advance (those starting with `strn` or, more primitive and effective, those starting with `mem`), others did not. To concatenate two strings you first had to allocate a sufficient buffer to contain the result etc.

The standard functions that process char pointers can still be found in STL, under the `<cstring>` header: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring, and `std::string` has synonymous methods `c_str()` and `data()` that return char pointers to its contents, should you need it.

When you write a program in C++, its `main` function has the header of `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, where `argv` is the array of char pointers that contains any command-line arguments your program was run with.

Ineffective as it is, this scheme could still be regarded as an advantage over strings of limited capacity or plain fixed-size character arrays, for instance in mid-nineties, when Borland introduced the `PChar` type in Turbo Pascal and added a unit that exported Pascal implementations of functions from C's string.h.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` and `const char*` are different types,  `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data)` means reinterpret the bits located at `&data` as `const char*`, which is not we want in this case.

so assuming we have type `A` and type `B`:

```cpp
A a;
B b;
```

the following are conversion:

```cpp
a = (A)b;                 //c sytle
// and                    
a = A(b);                 
// and 
a = static_cast<A>(b);    //c++ style
```

the following are bit reinterpretation:

```
a = *(A*)&b;                   //c style
// and
a = *reinterpret_cast<A*>(&b); //c++ style
```

finally, this should works:

```cpp
int main() {
    string data = "LetsTry";
    const char *ptr = data.c_str();
    cout<< ptr << "\n";
}
```

bit reinterpretation is sometimes used, like when doing bit manipulation of a floating point number, but there are some rules to follow like this one [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

also note that `cout << ptr << "\n";` is a specially case because feeds a pointer to `std::cout` usually output the address that pointer points to, but `std::cout` treats `char*` specially so that it output the content of that char array instead

Answer (score -1):

In C++, string is class and what you doing is creating a string object. So, to use are char * you need to convert it using *[c_str()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)*

You can refer below code:

```
std::string data = "LetsTry";

// declaring character array
char * cstr = new char [data.length()+1];

// copying the contents of the
// string to char array
std::strcpy (cstr, data.c_str());
```

Now, you can get use char * to point your data.

Comment: there's no reason to allocate memory just to point to a string. Just `ptr = data.c_str()` or `ptr = &data[0]` is enough. And even in case a new copy of the string is required, `memcpy` would be much better when the string length is known like this case

Comment: `memcpy` holds no advantage over `strcpy` here.

Comment: Thanks Amol , i tried this and i can copy the string constant in char sequence . but my intention was  to point the same address using data and cstr.

Comment: @RudraBindu: I guess what you are looking not possible being its C++ string object